# Парные повторения в списке

Tags: python

Нужна помощь в поиске парных повторений.

```
spisok = [1,2,3,4,1,2,7,8,21,33,15,3,4,1,23,17,1,2]
```

**Т.е числа (1 и 2) идут друг за другом и повторяются в списке 3 раза.
Так же 3, 4 и 1 фигурируют в списке 2 раза.**
На выходе должно получится это:

```
[1,2] - 3
[3,4,1] - 2
```

*В виде словаря, списка и т.д - не важно.*

Answer (score 0):

```
spisok = [1,2,3,4,1,2,7,8,21,33,15,3,4,1,23,17,1,2]
result = []
for n in range(2, len(spisok)):
    arr = [tuple(spisok[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(spisok) - n + 1)]
    result += ((el, arr.count(el)) for el in set(arr) if arr.count(el) > 1)

print(result)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]